# Add dynamic values to the options of plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery plugin
http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/

I'm in a situation where I need to add dynamic options/setting value to the plugin.

Example of working settings:

```
$input = $('.datepicker').pickadate({
              disable: [
                  { from: [2015,5,10], to: [2015,5,17] }
                 ]
           });
```

I'm want to create the from and to date from the database and here is my code:

booking_dates is an array output:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2015-06-02
                [1] => 2015-06-07
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2015-06-10
                [1] => 2015-06-15
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2015-06-16
                [1] => 2015-06-20
            )

    )

var booking_dates = ajax_object.booking_dates;
                var data = '';
                for(i = 0; i < booking_dates.length; i++ ) {
                    k = 0;

                    var from = booking_dates[i][k].split('-');
                    var to = booking_dates[i][++k].split('-');

                    if(i == 0) {
                        data = '{ from: [' + from[0] + ',' + (--from[1]) + ',' + from[2] + '], to: [' + to[0] + ','+ (--to[1]) + ',' + to[2] + '] }';
                    } else {
                        data = data + ', ' + '{ from: [' + from[0] + ',' + (--from[1]) + ',' + from[2] + '], to: [' + to[0] + ','+ (--to[1]) + ',' + to[2] + '] }';
                    }
                } 

                    alert (data); //{ from: [2015,5,15], to: [2015,5,20]}
```

data variable result is: `{ from: [2015,5,15], to: [2015,5,20] }`

but when I replace data with settings then it does not work:

DOES NOT WORK:

```
  $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate({
                            disable: [
                               data
                            ]
                    });
```

is it a string therefore not working? Or I have to create the options string in different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array of objects instead you are creating a string

```
var booking_dates = ajax_object.booking_dates;
var data = [];
for (i = 0; i < booking_dates.length; i++) {
    k = 0;

    var from = booking_dates[i][k].split('-');
    var to = booking_dates[i][++k].split('-');

    data.push({
        from: [from[0], --from[1], from[2]],
        to: [to[0], --to[1], to[2]]
    })
}

alert(data);

$input = $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    disable: data
});
```

Comment: I'm getting on alert [objectObject] and it is not working. can you help little bit more?

Comment: change `alert(data);` to `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` or better use `console.log(data)` and see whether the data format is proper

Comment: The output is strange http://screencast.com/t/R2P8MCyN. It has extra small brackets and double quotes around some values? It should be { from: [2015,5,10], to: [2015,5,17] }

Comment: @IrfanDayan what is the value of `ajax_object.booking_dates`?

Comment: I've updated my question with booking_dates actual values. It is an array with more than 1 values and I'm fetching this from database. Please check my updated question and would be nice if you help me with final piece of code.

Comment: @IrfanDayan can you check the view source and see what is the object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79523/discussion-between-irfan-dayan-and-arun-p-johny).

Comment: This is the result of booking_dates screencast.com/t/TvEqgyMj

Comment: I just used json_encode($booking_date_array) in my php fie and the result in browsers is screencast.com/t/TvEqgyMj
How can I can I convert the current json format into yours like this var ajax_object_t = {
booking_dates: [
["2015-6-10", "2015-6-15"],
["2015-6-18", "2015-6-19"]
]
}

Comment: @IrfanDayan http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vhj8xrp3/5/ - looks fine, now unless the problem is recreated there is nothing much to be done

Answer (score 0):

You should create proper an array and pass it.

```
var booking_dates = ajax_object.booking_dates;
var data = [];
for (i = 0; i < booking_dates.length; i++) {
    k = 0;
    var from = booking_dates[i][k].split('-');
    var to = booking_dates[i][++k].split('-');
    data.push({
        from: [from[0],  (--from[1]) , from[2]],
        to: to[0] , (--to[1]) , to[2]
    })   
}
```

Then use

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    disable: data
});
```